# Custom Odata v4 function - is not a valid odata route template - resource not found for the segment

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I have something in mind like this ( the action on itself is probably okay)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("GenerateFromProduct")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GenerateFromProduct([FromBodyAttribute] Product product)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        List<string[]> combos = new List<string[]>();
        List<ProductVariant> productVariants = product.GenerateProductVariants();
        db.ProductVariants.AddRange(productVariants);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(productVariants);
    }
```

The action defined in WebApiConfig would probably be something like this:

```
 builder.EntityType<ProductVariant>().Collection
 .Function("GenerateFromProduct").Returns<List<ProductVariant>>().EntityParameter<Product>("product");
```

But i keep getting the following error ( after several rewrites)

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.OData.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The path template 'GenerateFromProduct' on the action 'GenerateFromProduct' in controller 'ProductVariants' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? I didn't find a lot of information online about odata and custom functions / actions except the ones on msdn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@NicoJuicy

Your code:

```
builder.EntityType<ProductVariant>().Collection.Function("GenerateFromProduct")...
```

is to define a **Bound** function. A bound function is like the **instance method** that is called by instance.

Similar, the Uri template in `ODataRoute` should same as the bound function uri. So, it should be:

```
 [ODataRoute("ProductVariants/YourNameSpace.GenerateFromProduct(product={product}")]
```

Besides, function is only used in **GET** scenario, So, `[HttpPost]` is not correct for function.

Maybe the following material can help you to understand the function/action in OData:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/12/08/function-amp-action-in-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4-0-type-scenario.aspx#comments

And the following materials can help you to understand the function/action parameters:

- http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-06-function-parameter-support
- http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support

And the following materials can help you to understand the attribute routing:

- http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-03-attrribute-routing

Comment: I did made some progress on the routing ( made the first functions - bound and unbound, but i have a followup question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137197/odata-v4-productkey-generatevariants-route-misconfiguration . I'll consider this answer as valid, because my understanding about the routes and configuration in functions was / is still somewhat limited. I do now know that bound functions expect a entity to be returned ( or a model ).

It's still weird that odataController functions/actions needs to be seperately declared in WebApiConfig except when it's also on the model

Comment: PS. I'm missing some practical examples on the documentation and or github. Eg. i haven't found anywhere how i can declare an optional parameter which handles a route like [ODataRoute("Products({key})/GenerateVariants({save?}")] . I don't want to sound ungratefull, odata rocks, but some things are unclear :-)

Comment: optional parameter is not supported. However, you can define a parameter is nullable. for example `int?`.